# PHPUnit: How can I mock an HTTP request?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

How can I mock an HTTP request in order to write some tests about the data or STH like this?

```
public function serve_request() {

    // Check request method
    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET' ) {

        $this->send_response( 405, 'Invalid method: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] );
        die;

    }
```

For instance, how should I test the request method?
I've been confused for a little time. I also tried to curl the HTTP request but i couldn't access the data.
Any propositions is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

In your test you can directly modify $_SERVER to be different values.  So you then you would be able to test the different values.  So you could do `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'foo'` in your test before execution.

However because you have `die` in this function, this will halt the execution of phpunit.  In order to test this part of the function, the `die` command would need to be moved to a different location.  As it renders that part of the code untestable with phpunit.

Comment: I know i can directly modify $_SERVER values, but the thing is i wont be able to test the db data. Maybe, i would need to mock the HTTP request.

Comment: What db data? For that you would mock the db connection so that you can control it. But that is a different question.